# How to extract number before specific text with regular expression?

Tags: python

I try to extract the number before some specific text. So I have this long string:

```
verdi = "['a= (>)\n\nFactuur\nVerdi Import Schoolfruit\nFactuur nr; %: 70273 Koopliedenweg 38\nDeb. nr. : 108636 2991 LN BARENDRECHT\nYour VAT nr. : NL851703884B01 Nederland\nFactuur datum : 19-11-21\nAantal Omschrijving Prijs Bedrag\nOrder number : 76372 Loading date : 15-11-21 Incoterm: : FOT\nYour ref. : SCHOOLFRUIT Delivery date :\nWK46\nVerdi Import Schoolfruit\n566 Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I € 7,00 € 3.962,00\n706 Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I € 4,68 € 3.304,08\n598 Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I € 6,30 3.767,40\nOrder number : 76462 Loading date : 18-11-21 Incoterm: : FOT\nYour ref. : SCHOOLFRUIT Delivery date :\nWK47\nD.C, Schoolfruit\n176 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 125 Generica UY Klasse I € 6,25 € 1.100,00\n179 Peen Waspeen 14x1kg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I € 6,30 € 1.127,70\n222 Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I € 6,30 € 1.398,60\n270 Peen Waspeen 14x1ikg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I € 6,30 € 1.701,00\nZuid\n176 sinaas\n222 wortel\nmidden\n270 wortel\nNoord\n179 wortel\nOrder number : 75674 Loading date : 18-11-21 Incoterm: : FRA\nYour ref. : SCHOOLFRUIT Delivery date :\nWK47\nD.C. Schoolfruit\n400 Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 GENER DE Klasse I € 4,70 € 1.880,00\n129 Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 GENER DE Klasse I € 4,70 € 606,30\n48 Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 GENER IT Klasse I € 4,70 € 225,60\n104 = Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 GENER IT Klasse I € 4,70 € 488,80\n22 =Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 Viva IT Klasse I € 4,70 € 103,40\n107 ~=Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 Viva IT Klasse I € 4,70 € 502,90\n160 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 125 ALG ZA Klasse I € 7,50 € 1.200,00\n6 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 125 ALG ZA Klasse I € 7,50 € 45,00\n320 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 125 FVC ZA Klasse I € 7,50 € 2.400,00\nREGIO\nSINAAS\nMIDDEN: 219\nNOORD: 267\nVerDi Import BV ING Bank N.V. Rotterdam IBAN number: NL17INGB0006959173 aoethe\nKoopliedenweg 38, 2991 LN Barendrecht, The Netherlands SWIFT/BIC: INGBNL2A, VAT number: NL851703884B01\n\na\nTel. +31 (0)1 80 61 88 11, Fax +31 (0)1 80 61 88 25 Chamber of Commerce Rotterdam no. 55424309 VerDi\nE-mail: sales@verdiimport.nl, www.verdiimport.nl Dutch law shall apply. The Rotterdam District Court shall have exclusive jurisdiction.\n\nfrult and wegetadles\n\n \n\x0c', 'a> >)\n\nFactuur\nVerdi Import Schoolfruit\nFactuur nr. : 70273 Koopliedenweg 38\nDeb. nr. : 108636 2991 LN BARENDRECHT\nYour VAT nr. : NL851703884B01 Nederland\nFactuur datum ; 19-11-21\nAantal Omschrijving Prijs Bedrag\nRETTICH:\nZUID: 216\nNOORD: 328\nMIDDEN: 266\nTotaal Colli Totaal Netto Btw Btw Bedrag Totaal Bedrag\n\n     \n \n\n€ 23.812,78 € 25.955,93\n\n   \n\nBetaling binnen 30 dagen\nAchterstand wordt gemeld bij de kredietverzekeringsmaatschappij\n\nVerDi Import BV ING Bank N.V. Rotterdam IBAN number: NL17INGBO006959173 =\nKoopliedenweg 38, 2991 LN Barendrecht, The Netherlands SWIFT/BIC: INGBNL2A, VAT number: NL851703884B01 7\nTel. +31 (0)1 80 61 88 11, Fax +31 (0)1 80 61 88 25 Chamber of Commerce Rotterdam no. 55424309 VerD\nE-mail: sales@verdiimport.nl, www.verdiimport.nl Dutch law shall apply. The Rotterdam District Court shall have exclusive jurisdiction. l\n\nfrutt and vegetables:\n\n \n\x0c']"
```

and then I want to extract the number before this words:

```
fruit_words = ['Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I',
               'Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I', 
               'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I' ]
```

So I try it like this:

```
number_foud = re.findall(r"([0-9]+)" .join(fruit_words),verdi)
```

But if I try to run this with

```
print(number_foud)
```

it returns []

question: what I have to change,  that it will return the number before tex?

Thank you

for example 222 Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I

Comment: Try looking at what `r"([0-9]+)".join(fruit_words)` produces and be amazed =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `|` in the regular expression.

```
import re

verdi = "['a= (>)\n\nFactuur\nVerdi Import Schoolfruit\nFactuur nr; %: 70273 Koopliedenweg 38\nDeb. nr. : 108636 2991 LN BARENDRECHT\nYour VAT nr. : NL851703884B01 Nederland\nFactuur datum : 19-11-21\nAantal Omschrijving Prijs Bedrag\nOrder number : 76372 Loading date : 15-11-21 Incoterm: : FOT\nYour ref. : SCHOOLFRUIT Delivery date :\nWK46\nVerdi Import Schoolfruit\n566 Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I € 7,00 € 3.962,00\n706 Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I € 4,68 € 3.304,08\n598 Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I € 6,30 3.767,40\nOrder number : 76462 Loading date : 18-11-21 Incoterm: : FOT\nYour ref. : SCHOOLFRUIT Delivery date :\nWK47\nD.C, Schoolfruit\n176 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 125 Generica UY Klasse I € 6,25 € 1.100,00\n179 Peen Waspeen 14x1kg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I € 6,30 € 1.127,70\n222 Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I € 6,30 € 1.398,60\n270 Peen Waspeen 14x1ikg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I € 6,30 € 1.701,00\nZuid\n176 sinaas\n222 wortel\nmidden\n270 wortel\nNoord\n179 wortel\nOrder number : 75674 Loading date : 18-11-21 Incoterm: : FRA\nYour ref. : SCHOOLFRUIT Delivery date :\nWK47\nD.C. Schoolfruit\n400 Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 GENER DE Klasse I € 4,70 € 1.880,00\n129 Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 GENER DE Klasse I € 4,70 € 606,30\n48 Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 GENER IT Klasse I € 4,70 € 225,60\n104 = Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 GENER IT Klasse I € 4,70 € 488,80\n22 =Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 Viva IT Klasse I € 4,70 € 103,40\n107 ~=Rettich Klein x20 10kg 20 Viva IT Klasse I € 4,70 € 502,90\n160 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 125 ALG ZA Klasse I € 7,50 € 1.200,00\n6 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 125 ALG ZA Klasse I € 7,50 € 45,00\n320 Sinaasappels Valencias 15kg 125 FVC ZA Klasse I € 7,50 € 2.400,00\nREGIO\nSINAAS\nMIDDEN: 219\nNOORD: 267\nVerDi Import BV ING Bank N.V. Rotterdam IBAN number: NL17INGB0006959173 aoethe\nKoopliedenweg 38, 2991 LN Barendrecht, The Netherlands SWIFT/BIC: INGBNL2A, VAT number: NL851703884B01\n\na\nTel. +31 (0)1 80 61 88 11, Fax +31 (0)1 80 61 88 25 Chamber of Commerce Rotterdam no. 55424309 VerDi\nE-mail: sales@verdiimport.nl, www.verdiimport.nl Dutch law shall apply. The Rotterdam District Court shall have exclusive jurisdiction.\n\nfrult and wegetadles\n\n \n\x0c', 'a> >)\n\nFactuur\nVerdi Import Schoolfruit\nFactuur nr. : 70273 Koopliedenweg 38\nDeb. nr. : 108636 2991 LN BARENDRECHT\nYour VAT nr. : NL851703884B01 Nederland\nFactuur datum ; 19-11-21\nAantal Omschrijving Prijs Bedrag\nRETTICH:\nZUID: 216\nNOORD: 328\nMIDDEN: 266\nTotaal Colli Totaal Netto Btw Btw Bedrag Totaal Bedrag\n\n     \n \n\n€ 23.812,78 € 25.955,93\n\n   \n\nBetaling binnen 30 dagen\nAchterstand wordt gemeld bij de kredietverzekeringsmaatschappij\n\nVerDi Import BV ING Bank N.V. Rotterdam IBAN number: NL17INGBO006959173 =\nKoopliedenweg 38, 2991 LN Barendrecht, The Netherlands SWIFT/BIC: INGBNL2A, VAT number: NL851703884B01 7\nTel. +31 (0)1 80 61 88 11, Fax +31 (0)1 80 61 88 25 Chamber of Commerce Rotterdam no. 55424309 VerD\nE-mail: sales@verdiimport.nl, www.verdiimport.nl Dutch law shall apply. The Rotterdam District Court shall have exclusive jurisdiction. l\n\nfrutt and vegetables:\n\n \n\x0c']"

fruit_words = ['Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I',
               'Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I',
               'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I']

regex = r"([0-9]+)\s*(" + '|'.join(fruit_words) + ')'
print(regex)

numbers_found = re.findall(regex, verdi)
print(numbers_found)
```

The regex is

```
([0-9]+)\s*(Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I|Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I|Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I)
```

and the result is

```
[('566', 'Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I'), 
 ('706', 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I'), 
 ('598', 'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'), 
 ('222', 'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I')]
```

If `fruit_words` could contain characters with a special meaning for the regular expression, you should escape the words:

```
regex = r"([0-9]+)\s*(" + '|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in fruit_words) + ')'
```

And if you're not interested in the text belonging to that number you can ignore the group with `?:`.

```
regex = r"([0-9]+)\s*(?:" + '|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in fruit_words) + ')'
```

---

As noted in the comments the regular expression doesn't find some values. The reason is simple: the texts don't match. We're looking for "14x1lkg", but the texts are "14x1ikg" and "14x1kg".

If we change `'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'` in the fruit list to `'Peen Waspeen 14x1.?kg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'` and construct the regex with `r"([0-9]+)\s*(" + '|'.join(fruit_words) + ')'` the result is

```
[('566', 'Ananas Crownless 14kg 10 Sweet CR Klasse I'),
 ('706', 'Appels Royal Gala 13kg 60/65 Generica PL Klasse I'),
 ('598', 'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'),
 ('179', 'Peen Waspeen 14x1kg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'),
 ('222', 'Peen Waspeen 14x1lkg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I'),
 ('270', 'Peen Waspeen 14x1ikg 200-400 Generica BE Klasse I')]
```

Caveat: Since we use `.?` in the text now we can no longer use `re.escape`.

Comment: I have the text extracted from a image in a pdf. But is it also possible to make it generic. So regardless the text after the number, that it will show all the numbers before the text?